# Deligne-Lustzig varieties locally closed schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, deligne-lusztig-theory

I have a couple of questions about basic properties of of Deligne-Lustzig varieties introduced in the seminal paper "Representations of Reductive Groups Over Finite Fields" [[DL76]](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971021).

The central object in the paper is the reductive group $G$ over alg closed field of char $p>0$. The Deligne-Lustzig variety $X(w) \subset X$ (where $w \in W$ is an element in Weyl group and $X$ the set of all Borel groups on which $G$ acts by conjugation, which in turn inherits structure of a smooth projective homogeneous space of $G$) is defined as **locally closed** subscheme of $X$ consisting of all Borel subgroups $B$ of $G$ such that $B$ and $F(B)$ ($F:G \to G$ an isogeny, usually Frobenius) are in relative position $w$.

Main Question: Why is $X(w) \subset X$ locally closed as scheme?

Going maybe a step back an intermediate question: in the text the $G$-orbits wrt the action on $X$ and $X\times X$ are also seemingly regarded to carry naturally scheme structures too.

A guess: Do I understand it correctly that in case of the $G$-orbits considered in this paper one endows them with reduced scheme structure in following - let's say the most "naive" way comes into my mind:

By Chevalley's theorem any orbit is constructible, so $G \cdot x$ is open in it's topological closure $\overline{G \cdot x}$, and one "canonical" way to endow the orbit with scheme structure seems to be by endowing firstly the closed subset $\overline{G \cdot x} \subset X$ with reduced closed scheme structure, then $G\cdot x$ inherits as open set intrinsically scheme structure from  $\overline{G \cdot x}$. In other words: the orbits there carry only reduced structures?

Firstly, is this exactly this reduced scheme structure the considered orbits in the linked paper are endowed with or do the autors there mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any set which is open in its topological closure can be endowed with a reduced scheme structure in the way you disguise. The set will also be the intersection of an open set and a closed set, so you can do this the other way too: First pass to the open subscheme, then take the reduced subscheme structure on the closed set.

One can exactly endow the $G$-orbits on $X\times X$ with locally closed subscheme structure in this way, and then the Deligne-Lusztig variety is the pullback of one of these locally closed subschemes under the map $X \to X \times X $  that sends $B$ to $(B,\operatorname{Fr}(B))$.

The pullback of a locally closed set along a morphism of schemes is locally closed (since these morphisms are continuous) and the same holds for the inverse image of locally closed subschemes, so the main thing is to check that the map $X \to X \times X$ is actually a morphism of schemes which can be done using coordinates (it's basically $x \mapsto (x, x^q)$) or the structure of $G/B$ as a quotient.

However, for many purposes the choice of reduced subscheme structure or another structure for Deligne-Lusztig varieties is not so important since one is interested primarily in their étale cohomology which is independent of such choices.

Comment: Alright, so in context of DL- theory any involved orbit with scheme structure inherit it indeed really via this "naive" way from it's top closure, which in turn always considered with structure of reduced closed subscheme (...so there is nothing "non-natural" going on) , right so far? One another point I not completely got regarding checking that the map $X \to X \times X$ : Could you loose maybe a couple of words how to check that this map is a morphism and why it is "reasonable" to think it as $x \mapsto (x,x^q)$? In other words why the "set theoretic assignment $B \to (B,F(B))$ turns in an

Comment: honest algebraic map when we impose on $X$ structure of $G$- homogeneous space $G/N(B)$?

Comment: @user267839 The idea is that if we have any variety parameterizing Borels, it has some universal family so that the Borel corresponding to a point in the space is defined by polynomial equations whose coefficients are themselves polynomials in the coordinates of the space with finite field coefficients. Then raising the coordinates to the $q$th power has the effect of raising the coefficients of the polynomials to the $q$th power.

Comment: @user267839  But this has the effect of raising the set of solutions to the $q$th power - since $F$ is an injective homomorphism (of a field), the entries of a matrix satisfy some equations if and only if the $q$th power of the matrix satisfy those equations with the coefficients raised to the $q$th power.